# iOS simulator refuses to save screenshots

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Perhaps this is an effect of installing the new 4.5 beta, but my simulator won't save screenshots (at least not to the desktop).  Is there any setting that tells the simulator where to save?  I tried 5.0 and 5.1 in Xcode 4.3 and the menu blinks like it is doing something but no picture comes out.  Also nothing comes up in Spotlight.

Comment: If it is under NDA then you are not allowed to ask about it anywhere except the Apple developer forums.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist My question is about 4.3, not 4.5.  I'm just indicating that by installing another version of Xcode it may have messed with some settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm running 4.5 aswell, and **⌘ + S** just saves the screenshot to the desktop.

Did you try the "Copy Screen" option? You can then paste the image in any photo editing software.

EDIT: still works the same in 4.3 aswell

Comment: I can save it with Command shift 4, but I don't want the whole screen, including the bezel, just the inside.

Comment: I used to do it that way all the time, but now nothing happens o,0

Comment: It's an option in the simulator, Edit -> Copy Screen, then open up photoshop and just paste it

Comment: Copy screen works, but that's a real pain.  I have to makes hundreds of screenshots (to generate thumbnails of the screen) so being able to save them to the desktop really helps.  I wonder what the problem is...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286120/where-are-ios-5-simulator-screenshots-stored, some people there seem to have the same problem