# How can I take a screenshot of an iPhone5 app?

Tags: ios

The app store requires an iPhone5 screenshot:

"In order to save your changes, all iPhone 5 and iPod touch (5th gen) screenshots must be a .jpeg, .jpg, .tif, .tiff, or .png file that is 1136x640, 1136x600, 640x1136 or 640x1096 pixels, at least 72 DPI, and in the RGB color space."

I've tried using the iOS simulator and using the screenshot option, but this file is too small.

Does anyone know how to take one in a higher resolution?

I would use the design files but they don't have real data in them and will make my app look silly!

Any help would be appreciated - the forums and about three hours of google searching failed me :(

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the simulator doesn't take 1136x640 screenshots? Make sure your simulator is in the iPhone (Retina 4-inch) mode.

Comment: Change the simulator to a Retina device?  I use the iOS Simulator to create my screen shots.  Then I use Photoshop to clip the status bar.  I've done this for the 4 inch display as well.  Make sure you have an iOS Simulator that supports the 4 include display.

Comment: Also, short click Home + Power.

Comment: [The answers to this question may help you, too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286120/where-are-ios-5-simulator-screenshots-stored/8286150#8286150).

Comment: You guys are magic! I had the phone device settings wrong and now I can take a good screenshot! A side effect though - I discovered my app looks weird on the 5 so have to edit it again :S. On to the next problem :)

Answer (score 4):

Use your simulator and use control + command + C. This will copy only the screen of the simulator. Open preview and then file -> new from clipboard. This is far superior to trying to guess with command-shift-4.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

I use [iOS-Simulator Cropper](http://www.curioustimes.de/iphonesimulatorcropper/) to capture screenshots.  It automatically remove the carrier information from the top; the status bar.

[image: Screenshot of the app running on OSX]

Answer (score 1):

1. Launch iOS simulator from xCode 4.x
2. in the simulator, select the type of devices.
3. in the top menu 'file' > 'save screen shot'
4. find the file in the Finder 'iOS Simulator Screen .....'

Answer (score -1):

Use this code for taking a screen shot of any view. I have used it.

```
- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:myMapView
{
    [self captureScreenInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
}

- (UIImage *)captureScreenInRect:(CGRect)captureFrame
{
    CALayer *layer;
    layer = myMapView.layer;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myMapView.frame.size); 
    CGContextClipToRect (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),captureFrame);
    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *screenImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenImage, nil, nil, nil);
    return screenImage;
}
```